# [JavaScript]Add elements to a global array in a function and keep them

Tags: javascript, scope

```js
window.onload = function(){
    func1();
};

var list = [];

function func1(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    list.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(list);
```

Which the output log is an empty array, then how do I add elements to a global array in a function, and access them globally?

Answer (score 0):

Your function's code is fine.

However, you are logging the array using console.log before func1() gets to run, since window.onload fires AFTER everything has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on why the `console.log` in the end is empty.

Note that :

> window. onload() is invoked when all resources (the document, objects,
> images, css, etc) have finished rendering.

So after the `console` output the list value, if will execute the `func1` and assign the value to `list`, but before that `list` is just an empty array.

If could see the following snippet, if you put the `console` to the `window.onload` function, it works as epected.

You could use `push` to add item to array and use index to access a specific element.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    func1();
    console.log(list);
    func2()
    console.log(list)
};

var list = [];

function func1(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    list.push(i);
  }
}
console.log(list);
function func2(){
list[0] =9999

}
```

Comment: Sorry for confusing but the point is not to print them but access elements inside list, for example, I have another function that access the first element in the list

Comment: @M99996, if you want to access the first element in the list, use `list[0]`, is this would do want? I update the code, so you could the fun2 will change the first element in list to 9999. I don't know what you really want. If you don't could, you could edit it in your question, it will be easier for us~!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the window to load and call your function func1 before logging the value of the array to console...

```
window.onload = function(){
    func1();
    console.log(list);
};

var list = [];

function func1(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    list.push(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is right, you're getting an error because the browser is running func1() **before** the list array is rendered in. Just move it before window.onload() and you're good.

```js
const list = [];

window.onload = function(){
    func1();
};

function func1(){
  for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    list.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(list);
```